# What does Sinatra::Base.condition actually do?

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, block

I've come across the sinatra **condition** method and am puzzled in how it works.

I have a piece of code:

```
def auth user
  condition do
    redirect '/login' unless user_logged_in?
  end
end
```

Which checks to see if a user is logged for certain routes, an example route:

```
get '/', :auth => :user do
  erb :index
end
```

The method `user_logged_in?` is defined in a helper file in the lib directory of the project:

```
def user_logged_in?
  if session[:user]
    @user = session[:user]
    return @user
  end 
  return nil 
end
```

So, the question is: 
How does the `condition` block know what the `session[:user]` contains, when at the `get '/'` route the `session[:user]` hasn't even been set?

The `condition` method is defined in the following GitHub page: [sinatra base condition method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1138-1145)
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a route, the key of each member of the options hash is [called as a method, with the value passed as the arguments](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1204).

So when you do `get '/', :auth => :user do ...` the method `auth` gets called with the argument `:user`. This in turn calls the `condition` method with the block.

The `condition` method is actually [defined just above where you link to](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1118-1122) which is a *usage* of it. It looks like this:

```
def condition(name = "#{caller.first[/`.*'/]} condition", &block)
  @conditions << generate_method(name, &block)
end
```

The [`generate_method`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1196-1201) method converts the block into a method with the given name, and then this method is saved in the `@conditions` array. The contents of `@conditions` are then saved with the definition of the route, and `@conditions` is cleared ready for the next route definition.

At this point, the block of code passed to `condition` hasn't been executed. It has in effect been saved for later.

When an actual request comes in, if the request path matches the route, then [each condition associated with that route is executed](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L820) to check that it is fulfilled. In this example, this is when `redirect '/login' unless user_logged_in?` is first executed, so the `session` will have been set up and `session[:user]` will be available (or not if they're not logged in).

The important thing to understand about this is that when you pass a block to a method, the code in that block is not necessarily called right away. In this case the code in the block is only called when an actual request arrives.

Comment: thank you very much for careful explaination. My Ruby reading skills were totally stumped when I looked at the `condition` method. Even though reading through the code still feels quite painful you have allowed me to understand _what_ is going on. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Because Sinatra is responsible for calling both the condition methods and the route methods. Therefore, it should be safe to assume that whatever is set when your route method executes is also set when your condition execute.

Take a look at the code starting [here](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L819): conditions are called one by one; if all conditions match, then the block gets called. Nothing much happens between checking conditions and calling the block: they are basically run with the same context.

Comment: Thanks for this, @matt was able to show what's happening within the context of my programe, which is what I was after.